# How to validate two sets of radio buttons

Tags: jquery

I have two sets of radio buttons and I want to use return value from both sets and validate. User has to select at least one value from the two groups; user can select two values from two groups as well. I cannot throw an alert, I am using labels for errors on the page upon submission. 
What I cannot figure out is, how to give user freedom to select any radio button and error to go away if even one radio button is selected.

Here is my fiddle which is not working anymore.
http://jsfiddle.net/pQNNU/

I also used this:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var v1 = $('input:radio[name="attending_day_1"]:checked').val();
    var v2 = $('input:radio[name="attending_day_2"]:checked').val();

    if (!v1 && !v2 ) {
        $('.validation-error').html('*Please select attending day');
return false;
    } 
});
```

But this does not let my other fields validate from validate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea how inputs with the same names work (means within the same group) is that when you click on one radio button - all the rest with the same names will become unchecked.
To allow multiple selections - you'll have to give them different names.

To perform validation - you can wrap your set of inputs into div with id, for example. And then check if there is at least one checked item in inputs that are inside that div.

Actually, the better one variant is to use check boxes if you need multiple selections. Radio buttons purpose is for another tasks. But who knows what's your target :)

Short sample is here: http://jsbin.com/zacomuve/1/edit

Hopefully, this is what you need.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show an example? Yeah, I suggested checkboxes but I guess that's not what we're gonna do. Also, I am struggling with showing the error on page upon validation. Thanks

Comment: Updated answer with the sample. Hope this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks. i was able to do this on my own, but your answer is lot simpler. Thanks a lot.